# why does my multimeter show continuity (but no resistance) when not connected to anything?

Tags: electrical, tools, multimeter, resistance

Why does my multimeter show continuity (but no resistance) when not connected to anything?

Continuity is detected!
[image: continuity is detected!]

But no resistance is detected at 200 ohms.
[image: resistance not detected at 200 ohms]

Or 2 million ohms.
[image: 2 million ohms]

Comment: the scale selector is always for maximum range, so 200 Ohm should read lower values

Comment: Might be something wrong with it. I have the exact same model and it shows *.0L* in continuity mode.

Comment: Does the OL means open loop (not connected to anything)

Comment: From the manual: Test for continuity by connecting conductor or circuit with test
leads. If resistance is measured less than 100Ω, an audible signal will sound and display will show a resistance value indicating continuity. **If circuit is open, display will show "OL".**   So it has a fault or maybe it is in an electro/magnetic field (that is a wild guess).  What if you plug the leads in...do you get 0L?

Comment: I'll note that "no resistance" would commonly be taken to mean zero ohms, which is what you should expect to read across a switch that's "turned on", or from one end of a wire to the other end.

Comment: OL means extremely high resistance ... it indicates the resistance of the air gap between the two connectors on the DVM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a proper continuity, then open again, to see if it goes away, perhaps a charge is being held somewhere.

Otherwise, you may have a defective device, caused by measuring continuity while unintentionally applying a voltage, perhaps the line voltage.

Answer (score 0):

If there is power in the circuit you are measuring you will often get continuity. The ohms will depend on the circuits makeup. Continuity should always be completed with power to the circuit off.

Comment: Look at the picture. No wires, so no circuit, so no power.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Apologies I did not see them. WIth no probes connected to the meter there is clearly an internal fault in the continuity circuit. Yiu can have the meter calibrated. I believe Klein do a lifetime warranty with their products.